# Retrieve fieldname and value from case class object in scala, at runtime

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

An example case class: Was trying to create a generic query builder

```
case class BaseQuery(operand: String, value: String)
case class ContactQuery(phone: BaseQuery, address: BaseQuery)
case class UserQuery(id: BaseQuery, name: BaseQuery, contact: ContactQuery)

val user = UserQuery(BaseQuery("equal","1"), BaseQuery("like","Foo"), ContactQuery(BaseQuery("eq","007-0000"),BaseQuery("like", "Foo City")))


//case class Contact(phone: String, address: String)

//case class User(id: Long, name: String, contact: Contact)

//val user = User(1, "Foo Dev", Contact("007-0000","Foo City"))
```

How can we retrieve the field names and respective values in scala,

On further research,

Solutions using Scala Reflection:

```
def classAccessors[T: TypeTag]: List[MethodSymbol] = typeOf[T].members.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
}.toList

// The above snippet returns the field names, and as input we have to 
//feed the 'TypeTag' of the case class. And since we are only feeding a   
//TypeTag we will not have access to any object values. Is there any Scala
// Reflection variant of the solution.
```

Another solution,

```
def getMapFromCaseClass(cc: AnyRef) =
(scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Any]() /: cc.getClass.getDeclaredFields)
{
    (a, f) =>
        f.setAccessible(true)
        a + (f.getName -> f.get(cc))
}

// The above snippet returns a Map[String, Any] if we feed the case class 
//object. And we will need to match the map value to any of our other case 
//classes. If the class structure were simple, the above solution would be 
//helpful, but in case of complex case class this would not be the most efficient solution.
```

**Trying to:**

```
I am actually trying to retrieve the list of field and their values during runtime.

One of the use cases,

val list: Seq[Somehow(Field+Value)] = listingFieldWithValue(obj: UserQuery)
for(o <- list){
o.field.type match{
case typeOne: FooType =>{
//Do something
}
case typeTwo: FooBarType =>{
//Do something else
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not really `scala-reflect` solution, but [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) one. Shapeless is built on top of implicit macro, so it way faster than any reflection, if you have type information at compile time.

For implementation of your updated requirements you'll need some time to carry needed type information

```
sealed trait TypeInfo[T]{
  //include here thing you like to handle at runtime
}
```

Next you can define such info for different types and provide implicit resolution. In my example such implementation are also suitable for later matching

```
implicit case object StringField extends TypeInfo[String]

case class NumericField[N](implicit val num: Numeric[N]) extends TypeInfo[N]
implicit def numericField[N](implicit num: Numeric[N]): TypeInfo[N] = new NumericField[N]

case class ListField[E]() extends TypeInfo[List[E]]
implicit def listField[E] = new ListField[E]
```

Then we define more suitable for pattern matching result structure

```
sealed trait FieldDef
case class PlainField[T](value: Any, info: TypeInfo[T]) extends FieldDef
case class EmbeddedType(values: Map[Symbol, FieldDef]) extends FieldDef
```

So any result will be either value container with needed type info or container for deeper look.

Finally we can define concept implementation

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{ToTraversable, Mapper}

sealed abstract class ClassAccessors[C] {
  def apply(c: C): Map[Symbol, FieldDef]
}

trait LowPriorClassInfo extends Poly1 {
  implicit def fieldInfo[K <: Symbol, V](implicit witness: Witness.Aux[K], info: TypeInfo[V]) =
    at[FieldType[K, V]](f => (witness.value: Symbol, PlainField(f, info)))
}

object classInfo extends LowPriorClassInfo {
  implicit def recurseInfo[K <: Symbol, V](implicit witness: Witness.Aux[K], acc: ClassAccessors[V]) =
    at[FieldType[K, V]](f => (witness.value: Symbol, EmbeddedType(acc(f))))
}

implicit def provideClassAccessors[C, L <: HList, ML <: HList]
(implicit lgen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[C, L],
 map: Mapper.Aux[classInfo.type, L, ML],
 toList: ToTraversable.Aux[ML, List, (Symbol, FieldDef)]) =
  new ClassAccessors[C] {
    def apply(c: C) = toList(map(lgen.to(c))).toMap
  }

def classAccessors[C](c: C)(implicit acc: ClassAccessors[C]) = acc(c)
```

now

```
classAccessors(User(100, "Miles Sabin", Contact("+1 234 567 890", "Earth, TypeLevel Inc., 10")))
```

will result to

```
 Map(
 'id -> PlainField(100, NumericField( scala.math.Numeric$LongIsIntegral$@...)),
 'name -> PlainField("Miles Sabin", StringField), 
 'contact -> EmbeddedType( Map(
      'phone -> PlainField( "+1 234 567 890", StringField), 
      'address -> PlainField("Earth, TypeLevel Inc., 10", StringField))))
```

Comment: would not this approach be similar to the second solution I had posted, where I would need to match 'Value' [Symbol, Value->Any] to a certain class?

Comment: @mane Actually I did adapt it to your second case. What result type do you need ? As shapeless has complete type information at compile level, it could be adapted to anything.

Comment: Also as you can see it contains embedded `Map` object, so it's making full recursive conversion.

Comment: @odmontois I have added a use case, I tried to be as descriptive as possible, hope it helped. Updated the question. I was just trying to omit a process layer, where I would need to compare 'Any' to the list of case classes i would have.